# How to create a shaking/floating animation to an image (react native)

Tags: react-native

I want to create a shaking/floating (call it what you want) animation to an image.

Basically the image will float or wiggle left to right and at the same time up and down.
The animation will be triggered automatically.

This is the component I have. Image is a round ball so nothing fancy.

I tried putting values in inputRange and outputRange but nothing happened. Probably because it doesn't trigger the animation (?).

New to react native, not even sure if below is a good start to my animationgoal.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Animated } from "react-native";
import Images from "./assets/Images";

export default class Round extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0);
  }

  render() {

    let float = this.animatedValue.interpolate({
      inputRange: [],
      outputRange: [],
    });

    return (
      <Animated.Image
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          left: x,
          top: y,
          width: width,
          height: height,
          transform: { translate: float },
        }}
        resizeMode="stretch"
        source={Images.round}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I used the react-native-animatable library to solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

I have created something similar to iPhone delete app screen, where all icons wiggle.

You can decrease duration field to increase the speed of wiggle.

```js
const spinValue = new Animated.Value(0);

useEffect(() => {
  Animated.loop(
    Animated.sequence([
      Animated.timing(spinValue, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 30,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }),
      Animated.timing(spinValue, {
        toValue: 2,
        duration: 40,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }),
    ]),
  ).start();
}, [spinValue]);

const spin = spinValue.interpolate({
  inputRange: [0, 1, 2],
  outputRange: ['0deg', '2deg', '-2deg'],
});


**
JSX **
  <
  Animated.View
style = {
    [
      styles.container,
      styles.deleteContainer,
      {
        transform: [{
          rotate: spin
        }],
      },
    ]
  } >
  <
  Image
style = {
  [styles.thumb, styles.deleteContainer]
}
source = {
  {
    uri: item.thumbnailUrl
  }
}
/> <
/Animated.View>


deleteContainer: {
  opacity: 0.85,
  borderRadius: 5,
  borderColor: 'red',
  borderWidth: 1.4,
},
```

Comment: When I try this I get error 'Invalid hook call. hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component'. Can't convert this to a functional comp since I'm using props.body 

Comment: Updated post above with full file after your suggested insertions, which gives me the error I mentioned in comment above

Comment: I used a library to solve my problem

Comment: UseEffect cannot be used inside a class component. You can use functional component or alternative life cycle hooks in classes.

Comment: Yes, that's what I stated in the comment above about the error